# Testing role silex

Tags: php, silex

I have a problem with flint, I do not understand why he never returns TRUE me to the test ROLE.
My current user is the one show with $ username isGranted but returns me only FALSE.

Do you have an idea ?

```
$token  = $app['security.token_storage']->getToken();
$user   = $token->getUser();
echo $username = $user->getUsername(); // Good return !!


if ($app['security.authorization_checker']->isGranted('ROLE_USER'))
    echo 'Never return also my user is ROLE_USER';
else
    echo 'always return';
```

PS :My users is generate by Symfony

My firewall Silex :

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
'security.firewalls' => array(
    'main'   => array(
        'pattern'   => '^/',
        'guard'     => array(
            'authenticators' => array(
                'api.token_authenticator'
            ),
        ),
        'users'     => function () use ($app) {
            return new UserProvider($app['db']);
        },

        'anonymous' => true,
    ),
),
'security.role_hierarchy'   => array(
    'ROLE_USER'             => array(),
    'ROLE_ADMIN'            => array('ROLE_USER'),
    'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'      => array('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH'),
),
));
```

var_dump($user) return :

```
    object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User)#255 (7) {
  ["username":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User":private]=>
  string(23) "test@test.com"
  ["password":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User":private]=>
  string(60) "$2y$13$8sv57a29wd9Xg0gc0o0ckOP3.pN9g2ZOuAwaldRdrPOk.XA9Dp8m"
  ["enabled":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User":private]=>
  bool(true)
  ["accountNonExpired":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User":private]=>
  bool(true)
  ["credentialsNonExpired":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User":private]=>
  bool(true)
  ["accountNonLocked":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User":private]=>
  bool(true)
  ["roles":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User":private]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(34) "a:1:{i:0;s:16:"ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN";}"
  }
}
```

Thank's

Comment: Can you share your firewall configuration and your access rules?

Comment: Hi ! I just edit my first post

Comment: Can you try to add some [access rules](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html#defining-access-rules)?

Comment: By adding a rule I'm still stuck, it returns me I do not have access.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried both options? What Silex version are you using?

```
// Symfony 2.6+
if ($app['security.authorization_checker']->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
    // ...
}

// Symfony 2.3/2.5
if ($app['security']->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hello,

I use the latest version of Silex either version 2.0
I used both the right method to test the role ...

Answer (score 0):

I still have not managed to solve this problem ...
I do not know if this is helpful but this is my composer file:

```
{
"name": "Acme/api",
"license": "proprietary",
"type": "project",
"description" : "API Project",
"require": {
    "silex/silex": "~2.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "2.5.*",
    "symfony/security": "^3.1",
    "symfony/twig-bridge": "^3.1",
    "symfony/translation": "3.1.*",
    "symfony/config": "3.1.*",
    "symfony/browser-kit": "3.1.*",
    "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bridge": "3.1.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "5.5.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"Api\\": "src"}
}
}
```

EDIT :

I found but I do not know how to solve the problem, Symfony records Actual via serialize, Flint or used directly in the right role string directly in the database.

The isGranted method does not support the de-serialization roles.

Why Symfony and Silex does not he uses the same management roles?

How to take into account the serialize?